# Delegate permission to alter smtp aliases on a specific email address in Microsoft Exchange 2013

Tags: active-directory, permissions, exchange, powershell, exchange-2013

I'd like to be able to grant permission to a particular Security Group to be able to create/alter the SMTP addresses for a specific mailbox. Happy for this to be done via GUI or via PowerShell. I can find nothing about this level of granularity through Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638132(v=exchg.150).aspx

To manage Email addresses, you need to be part of the Exchange roles below.
-Organization Management
-Recipient Management
-UM Management

From the above link, each of these roles has a hyperlink for further information.

http://exchangeserverpro.com/manually-configuring-email-addresses-for-exchange-server-2013-recipients-using-powershell/ is a good article on how to modify email addresses. From the ExchangeServerPro article:

```
Set-Mailbox Paul.Cunningham -EmailAddresses @{Add='paulc@exchange2013demo.com'}
```

Adds an additional email address without removing the existing ones.

To check which Management Roles you have access to, use:

```
Get-ManagementRoleAssignment
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351024(v=exchg.150).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335173(v=exchg.150).aspx might also be what you are looking for.

http://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-manage-role-based-access-control-in-exchange-2013/ also has a comprehensive document on Role Based Access Control.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.